# mySQL group records with latest entry from child table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 3 tables office, Computer and Maintain. Office just list of offices, computers belongs to office as well as has many Maintains.

**I want to LEFT join all tables with just the latest entry from Maintain table.** *The code below works but it just group the oldest entry in the maintain.*

```
SELECT `Computer`.`id`, `Computer`.`control`, `Computer`.`operator`, `Computer`.`datePurchased`, `Computer`.`type`, `Computer`.`property`, `Computer`.`printer`, `Computer`.`scanner`, `Computer`.`osx`, `Computer`.`applications`, `Computer`.`licence`, `Computer`.`isStandAlone`, `Computer`.`isInternet`, `Computer`.`isNetwork`, `Computer`.`generalStatus`, `Computer`.`ip_address`, `Computer`.`mac_address`, `Computer`.`user_id`, `Computer`.`office_id`, `Computer`.`created`, `Computer`.`modified`, `Computer`.`deleted`, `Office`.`id`, `Office`.`description`, `Office`.`main_office`, `Maintain`.`id`, `Maintain`.`dateEncoded`, `Maintain`.`findings`, `Maintain`.`checkedBy`, `Maintain`.`remarks`, `Maintain`.`computer_id`, `Maintain`.`created`, `Maintain`.`modified`, `Maintain`.`user_id` FROM `computers`.`computer` AS `Computer`

LEFT JOIN `computers`.`office` AS `Office` 
ON (`Office`.`id` = `Computer`.`office_id`)

LEFT JOIN `computers`.`maintain` AS `Maintain`
ON (`Computer`.`id` = `Maintain`.`computer_id`)

LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(dateEncoded) maxDate, findings FROM maintain GROUP BY computer_id) AS `P2`
ON (`Maintain`.`dateEncoded` = `p2`.`maxDate`) 

WHERE `Office`.`main_office` LIKE '%CVPH MON%'
GROUP BY `Computer`.`id` 
ORDER BY `Office`.`description` ASC
```

SAMPLE

```
OFFICE
1    AAAA
2    BBBB

COMPUTER
id   name   office_id
1    CP1    1
2    CP2    1
3    CP3    2

Maintain
id   description   date        computer_id
1     Fix         06/20/2014    1
2     Fix         06/11/2014    1
3     Fix         06/12/2014    2
4     Fix         06/15/2014    2


Result if query on computer=CP1 should be
Office     Computer_name    Maintain_desc    Date
AAA         CP1               Fix           06/20/2014   <- Latest entry in maintain
```

Comment: Provide sample data set @http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: pls see edited post.. trying to give sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so

```
SELECT `c`.`id`, 
`c`.`name`, 
`c`.`office_id` ,
`o`.`name` office_name, 
`m`.`date`,
`m`.`description`
FROM `computer` AS c
LEFT JOIN `office` AS `o` 
ON (`o`.`id` = `c`.`office_id`)
LEFT JOIN `maintain` AS m
ON (`c`.`id` = `m`.`computer_id`)
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT computer_id,MAX(`date`) maxdate 
 FROM maintain 
 GROUP BY computer_id ) t
ON(m.`date`=t.maxdate AND m.computer_id= t.computer_id)
 WHERE `c`.`name` ='CP1' ... more conditions
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/197de4/1)

Comment: by the way, this is good when there are entries in maintain table since it uses INNER join. But this doesn't work with LEFT join. Is there any way to force display the computer even without entries in the maintain?

Comment: No the last join needs to be inner if not then it will result multiple entries